# opencart custom controller not found

Tags: php, opencart-3

im trying to write a custom controller in my website
i added a new folder named ticketing in "catalog/controller" directory
then added a php file for the controller

```
  <?
    class ControllerTicketingTicket extends Controller{
     public function index(){
        var_dump("hi");

     }
     public function addticket(){

     }

}
```

now when I'm trying to request the route "route=ticketing/ticket"

**response**

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controllerticketingticket' not found in myurl\system\storage\modification\system\engine\action.php on line 71
[image: the response with fatal error]

Answer (score 2):

You want to ruin OC framework. You are allowed use this folders:

```
$allowed = array(
'admin/controller/extension/',
'admin/language/',
'admin/model/extension/',
'admin/view/image/',
'admin/view/javascript/',
'admin/view/stylesheet/',
'admin/view/template/extension/',
'catalog/controller/extension/',
'catalog/language/',
'catalog/model/extension/',
'catalog/view/javascript/',
'catalog/view/theme/',
'system/config/',
'system/library/',
'image/catalog/'
);
```

For example if you need to create custom module you should add your custom module file for admin to:
`admin/controller/extension/module/ticketing/ticketing.php`
and your file should start:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleTicketingTicketing extends Controller {
```

**The path and the extend should be with the same names** and each word in a class must start in  uppercase.

the same for  the "catolog"

Comment: This video may also be helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9ICKANhfNk

Comment: i did what you said and still the same problem!!

Comment: still the same,im starting to think that my installation may have problems

Comment: existing controller that were created by the theme or extensions are working properly